# Edit files on Aws ec2

Tags: php

New to AWS. Need help in regards to editing a php file of an application hosted on ex2.

I'm able to connect to my ex2 via Putty and am able to locate and edit the php file. But when I refresh the browser cannot see my changes.

It's an Linux Ami.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks Fabian.
The Php file is just one from the application not any configuration file. It's got a harmless form element.

However I'm not sure of any framework being used, as this application was developed by another developer who is not with the business.

As I'm trying to get a hang of the app, I tried and edited a text string within the php/htm file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide more information about the php file you are changing. Is it a configuration file? Which framework are you using? Did you disable your browser-cache?